# Job Agent sysjobhistory run_status=0 failure but which last step was a failure?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs

I am getting confusing results from `sysJobHistory`. The message can sometimes say last step was 2 but the row from instance_id says 0.

Below are some examples below when `run_status=0`.

Any idea how to interpret the sysjobhistory table?

```
**instance_id   step_id step_name   message**                           
1534624 0   (Job outcome)   The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User     GAIA\gai_svc_sql_vis.  The last step to run was step 2 (Transform Intelligence).                           
1537487 0   (Job outcome)   The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule     4131 (Dagligen).  The last step to run was step 5 (Ladda Basmart).
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this query helps, it should relay failed jobs and some basic information regarding them from the history table. I have included a few other filters and their explanations below too.

```
           SELECT
                j.[name] AS [name]
                ,s.step_name AS [step_name]
                ,h.step_id AS [step_id]
                ,h.step_name AS [step_name]
                ,h.run_date AS [run_date]
                ,h.run_time AS [run_time]
                ,h.sql_severity AS [sql_severity]
                ,h.message AS [message]
                ,h.server AS [server]
                ,h.instance_id
                ,s.command
            FROM
                msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
            ON  h.job_id = j.job_id
            INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
            ON  j.job_id = s.job_id AND
                h.step_id = s.step_id
            WHERE
                h.run_status = 0 -- Failure
```

You can limit the results by date with `h.run_date` and also the name of the job with the field `j.name`.

[Here is the MSDN on sysjobhistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> The message can sometimes say last step was 2 but the row from
>   instance_id says 0.

`instance_id` is just a unique identifier for the row in the table.